# Pandas series pad function not working with apply in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write the code to pad columns of my pandas dataframe with different characters. I tried to use apply function to fill '0' with *zfill* and it works.

```
print(df["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.zfill(10)))
```

But when I try to use pad function using apply method to my dataframe I face error:
*AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pad'*

The code I am trying is:

```
 print(df["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.pad(10, side="left", fillchar="0")))
```

Both the *zfill* and *pad* functions are a part of *pandas.Series.str*. I am confused why *pad* is not working and *zfill* works. How can I achieve this functionality?

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

StringData = StringIO(
    """Date,Time
パンダ,パンダ
パンダサンＤＡ１２－３,パンダーサンＤＡ１２－３
ﾊﾟﾝﾀﾞｻﾝDA12-3,ﾊﾟﾝﾀﾞｻﾝDA12-3
    """
)

df = pd.read_csv(StringData, sep=",")

print(df["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.zfill(10))) -- works
print(df["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.pad(10, side="left", fillchar="0"))) -- doesn't work
```

I am using *pandas 1.5.1*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just not use `apply`, doing so you don't benefit from **Series** methods, but rather use pure python **str** methods:

```
print(df["Date"].str.zfill(10))
print(df["Date"].str.pad(10, side="left", fillchar="0"))
```

output:

```
0       0000000パンダ
1      パンダサンＤＡ１２－３
2    ﾊﾟﾝﾀﾞｻﾝDA12-3
Name: Date, dtype: object
0       0000000パンダ
1      パンダサンＤＡ１２－３
2    ﾊﾟﾝﾀﾞｻﾝDA12-3
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

##### multiple columns:

Now, you need to use `apply`, but this is [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), not [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].apply(lambda s: s.str.pad(10, side="left", fillchar="0"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. How can I scale this up to multiple columns? I could have used applymap to make it work for multiple columns.

Comment: Let me update the answer

Comment: Okay it works. Can you please let me know why zfill works here with Series.apply for a single column and pad is not working in the same way.

Comment: Because, `zfill` is also a python `str` method (`'1'.zfill(3)` -> `001`), while `pad` is not, you were **not** using the `Series.str.zfill` method here